# Monodroid Listview

Tags: xamarin.android

I have tried making a listview for a android app like [this tutorial](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/User_Interface/list_view).

However, when I tried making it, VS2010 started whining about an error, not sure what it means.

I hope someone can help me.

This is the error:

> Activity1.OnCreate(Android.OS.Bundle)': cannot change access modifiers
>   when overriding 'protected' inherited member
>   'Android.App.Activity.OnCreate(Android.OS.Bundle)'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the error message you need to change:

```
public override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
```

to

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
```

Comment: You are welcome and welcome to stackoverflow! Keep in mind that if a answer solves or helps you solve your question, you should click on the checkmark and up arrow next to the answer so that future visitors to this question know that is the answer that worked for you.